# How to get the value in javascript from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

How to know the user's name with javascript

```
[
  {
    id: 3843558,
    cid: 4070139,
    text: ' Hi today',
    user: 'Eklavya',
    rto: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    time: 1616050866
  }
]
```

Comment: `for (var obj of arr) console.log(obj.user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
   {
     id: 3843558,
     cid: 4070139,
     text: ' Hi today',
     user: 'Eklavya',
     rto: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     time: 1616050866
   }
 ]
    //If multiple object exist..
    const users = arr.map(obj=>{
      return obj.user
    })

    //For single object
    let name = arr[0].user
   
    //OR
    let name = (arr[0])['user']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is called `users` then in this case `users[0].user` or `users[0]['user']`.  `users = JSON.parse(str)` if you have string `str`.  `fs = require('fs'); fs.readFile(file, [encoding], [callback]);` if you need to read the string from file (nodejs).